# Looping variables with empty value

Tags: bash

I have a some variables

VAR1=1

VAR2=

VAR3=3

I want to pace it through loop & give a null value to those which are empty.

for somevar in $VAR1 $VAR2 $VAR3

do

test -z $somevar && $somevar=null

done

But it is not working :(

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to assign a default value to each variable. eg:

```
${VAR:=value}
```

This sets the value of `$VAR` to "value" if it's unset or null.

To answer your specific question about why your code isn't working, it's probably because you're doing

```
$somevar=null
```

rather than:

```
somevar=null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the variable with a literal string 'null' you can do:

```
for somevar in VAR1 VAR2 VAR3; do
    [[ -z ${!somevar} ]] && eval "${somevar}=null"
done
```

That's safe. Just make sure that the variable names are valid.